# Uniqueness of roots system of a semisimple Lie algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, root-systems

Take $L$ a $\mathbb{C}$-Lie algebra with finite dimension and semisimple. Now take $H \subset L$ a maximal toral subalgebra we can define the roots system associated to $(L,H)$ as the set of maps $H\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ which appear as eigenvalue of $H$ for the adjoint representation.

I would want to prove that the roots system doesn't depend from the choice of $H$.

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What are your thoughts? Since generally in such a situation there are several choices of $H$, I would wonder if those maximal toral (= Cartan) subalgebras are related to each other, maybe have a special kind of isomorphism between them?

Comment: Yes, I've found a solution. The maximal toral subalgebras as always conjugated and this is sufficient from structure theorems